# google url shortener not returning a url

Tags: jquery, json, url-rewriting, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

i am just trying to make a simple ajax call to shorten a url using googles url shortener, but its not returning any data. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: {longUrl: match},
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(id){
                  $('#menu').html(id);
                  }
                });
```

I have an API key but i just didnt put it in here. and you dont need one to use the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the api library rendered by google for url shortner, its available in php, java , .net etc.,

Link to API libraries - http://code.google.com/apis/urlshortener/libraries.html

Else your ajax need to done for cross domain ajax, [read this](https://github.com/mustardamus/cross-domain-ajax-demo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your apikey also. Like this:

```
           $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=YOUR_API_KEY",

              data: {longUrl: match},
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(id){
                 $('#menu').html(id);
              }
            });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: you don't need an api key to use it, but i do have one and i am using it, and its returning nothing.